# Using Capybara live without RSpec

Tags: ruby, selenium, capybara, automated-tests

I'd like to use Capybara for live testing, outside RSpec. Just as I'd do using pure Selenium. Is it possible to build scenarios and do logs this way? If not and I have to stick with Selenium - how can I create scenarios and do logs using Ruby?

Comment: You want to use Capybara together with some kind of test framework to get access to assert methods. You can use selenium as driver in capybara. Or - as I prefer - webkit. Browse through the [front page documentation](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara) and it is all there. Why don't you want to use rspec? and what do you mean with "pure selenium"? The recording functionality? If recording is what you are after then capybara is probably not your best choice.

Comment: I don't know what "build scenarios and do logs" means. It would be way easier to help you if you gave an example of what you're trying to do.

Comment: I'd like to use Capybara just the way I do in RSpec/feature spec test, but not using local Ruby project but a normal, production website:)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can [manually create a Capybara session](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara#using-the-sessions-manually) and use that to interact with your production website. For example, the following will go to Google and get the text:

```
require 'capybara'

session = Capybara::Session.new(:selenium)
session.visit('https://www.google.com')
puts session.text
```

Note that neither Capybara nor RSpec require the system under test to be a local Ruby project. For example, the following RSpec test goes to Google and checks that the word "Google" appears:

```
require 'capybara/rspec'

Capybara.current_driver = :selenium
Capybara.app_host = 'http://www.google.com'

feature "google", :js => true do
    scenario "should have text" do
        visit('/')
        page.should have_content(/Google/)
    end
end
```